# PHP replacing for with do while

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I need to write the following piece of code with a do while and not with a for loop, how would I do this?

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    for($i2=1;$i2<=10;$i2++)
    { 
        if(($i*$i2)%2==0)
        {
            echo "<td>" . $i*$i2 . "</td>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>" . $i*$i2 . "</td>"; 
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked out this [ref](http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.do.while.php)?

Comment: don't use a variable names `$i2`. This is a very bad practice. It is generally accepted that loop variables be named one of three things. `$i`, `$j`, and `$k`. Use them in that order. Though, if you reach `$k`, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A do-while loop the way I think you want it should look like this:

```
$i = 1; // initiate condition variable
// start the loop
do {
   // some code
   $i++; // increment condition variable
}
while ($i <= 10); // the loop condition
```

So your code with a do-while loop should something look like this:

```
echo "<table>";

$i = 1; // initiate $i to 1
// start outer loop
do { 
    $i2 = 1; // initiate $i2 to 1

    echo "<tr>";
    // start inner loop
    do {
        if(($i*$i2)%2==0)
        {
            echo "<td>" . $i*$i2 . "</td>"; 
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>" . $i*$i2 . "</td>"; 
        }
        $i2++; // increment $i2
    }
    while ($i2 <= 10); // inner loop condition

    echo "</tr>";
    $i++; // increment $i
}
while ($i <= 10); // outer loop condition

echo "</table>";
```

Resource: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven Well, thanks for ignoring the fact that my answer came first…

Comment: @e-sushi yours gave me an error, sorry..

Comment: @MatthiasVerhoeven Are you sure you copy-and-pasted it correctly? I added a screenshot to my answer showing my code works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know how you would do this, but I would do it like this…

```
  <?php
  echo "<table>";
  $a = 1;
  do
  {
      echo "<tr>";
      $b=1;
      do
      {
          if((($a * $b) % 2) == 0)
          {
              echo "<td>" .($a * $b). "</td>";
          }
          else
          {
              echo "<td>" . ($a * $b) . "</td>";
          }
          $b++;
      } while($b<=10);
      echo "</tr>";
      $a++;
  } while($a<=10);
  echo "</table>";
  ?>
```

That replaces every `for/next` with a `do/while` as you requested.

Please note that I also took the freedom to replace `$i` and `$i2` with `$a` and `$b`, since that is more readable. Last but not least, I added some “()” here and there which will avoid potential code problems.

**EDIT**

Here's the result:

[image: screenshot of output]

The general logic behind do/while loops is the following:

```
do { /* something */ } while (/* condition */);
```